# Copying files into directory by date in R

Tags: r

I have a large number of image files, taken over the course of several months, stored in a single directory. I'm trying to copy the files into a series of new directories, with one directory for each week of photos, all contained within a directory for the site where they were take (so all the photos taken in week 12 at site TMC wind up in `../TMC/week_12` and so on). I also need a csv in each directory listing all of the files for that week with their timestamp. The csv and the directory creation are fine, but I'm having trouble copying the files into the correct folders.

```
library('lubridate')
library('purrr')

# photo.df is a data frame with all of the photos, their full filepath, and the timestamp when they were taken.

site.dir <- 'D:/photos/TMC'

# Split the data frame by week.
by.week <- split(photo.df, week(photo.df$datetime))

# Create a subfolder for each week.
walk(seq_along(by.week), function(x){
  dir.create(paste(site.dir, '/', 'week_',
                       as.character(x), sep=''))
})

# Save a list of each week's photos as its own csv in the appropriate subfolder.
walk(seq_along(by.week), function(x){
  write.csv(by.week[[x]],
            file=paste(site.dir, '/', 'week_', as.character(x), '/',
                       site, '_photos_', as.character(x), '.csv', sep=''),
            row.names=FALSE)
})
```

And that's where I get stuck. How do I select all the image files for a given week and copy them into the appropriate file, given that I have many weeks-worth of files? I realize R may not be the best tool for this job, but the rest of my workflow is in R so it's what I have. Because the `by.week` data frame contains the full file path for each photo, I thought I could combine `by.week[[x]]$filepath` and `file.copy()` with a function to automate the process, but I'm not quite sure how to make it happen. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help, I was able to work out this solution.

```
library('lubridate')
library('purrr')

# photo.df is a data frame with all of the filenames of all the photos and the timestamp when they were taken.

photo.df$timestamp <- ymd_hms(photo.df$timestamp)

site.dir <- 'D:/photos/TMC'
path.in <- 'D:/101RECNX/'

# Add a week column.
photo.df <- photo.df %>%
  mutate(week=week(datetime), week=paste0('week_', week))

# Nest the data frame by week.
photo.nest <- photo.df %>% group_nest(week)

# Make a separate csv and directory for each nested week.
walk2(photo.nest$week, photo.nest$data, function(week, data) {
  path <-  paste0(site.dir, '/', week, '/', site, '_photos_', week, '.csv')
  dir.create(dirname(path), recursive=TRUE, showWarning=FALSE)
  write.csv(data, file=path, row.names=FALSE)
})

# Copy the photos into the appropriate directories.
walk2(photo.df$week, photo.df$filename, function(week, filename) {
  target <-  paste0(site.dir, '/', week, '/', filename)
  source <- file.path(path.in, filename)
  file.copy(source, target)
})
```

Hope someone else finds that useful!